# KALLYAS theme with WooCommerce plugin - Cannot remove sidebar on "Shop" page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using KALLYAS theme with WooCommerce plugin for an online store. My problem is, I can't remove the right sidebar on the Shop page. I tried several page layouts on this theme. But sidebar never goes. If I removed the sidebar from KALLYAS them options, it affects to other pages as well. Such as blog page. (I need sidebar on the blog page).

So, if anyone have an idea of a solution, please be kind enough to reply...

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the sidebar programmatically?

Comment: @Dolchio, thanks for your reply. Actually, not. I didn't try to edit the code of the template. I don't know how to remove only the shop page's sidebar. Sometimes it can affect to other pages. So, I didn't do anything with editing core files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the page layout is set to **"No sidebar"**,  along with the **"Defualt - Set from theme options"** sidebar selected just like in the picture below. Also did you try to empty cache and hard reload? HAHA
[image]

Comment: Ok, Tyree, I'll try :)